# PHP: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in file.php

Tags: php, mysql, server

I am coding PHP and here is my code:

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user = $stmt->bind_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but I am getting this error and this warning and do not know how to solve it:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in file.php
>
> Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_result() in file.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION 1** if you have MySQL Native Driver (mysqlnd) installed  you can use

```
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

more info here with examples: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli

**OPTION 2** if no then use it with `bind_result`, more info here for bind_result: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

```
// IMPOTANT: you need to change your sql query to select 
// only columns which you need unique_id, name, email ...
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT unique_id, name, email FROM users WHERE email = ?");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();

// list here variables with exact amount of columns which you selecting in your query 
$stmt->bind_result($row_user_id, $row_user_name, $row_user_email);

// In case you expect 1 row 
$stmt->fetch();
var_dump($row_user_id, $row_user_name, $row_user_email);// to see result
$user = array(
     'id' => $row_user_id, 
     'name' => $row_user_name,
     'email' => $row_user_email,
);

// In case you expect many rows use while 
$users = array();
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
   $users[] = array(
        'id' => $row_user_id, 
        'name' => $row_user_name,
        'email' => $row_user_email,
   );
}
var_dump( $users );// to see result
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. i did that but now there is this error:

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: seems there is some problem with your `stmt` can you dump `var_dump($stmt)` after `$stmt->execute();` what it gives you ?

Comment: I found article about that erro here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389709/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result, and updated my answer you can check it again

Comment: you mean, with bind_result(col1, col2); ,  now I have a row?? i am a bit mixed up here and I am new in php, would you please explain more?please

Comment: sry to bother u again, but would please look at my code? because error_log is empty and yet still i am getting server error 500 and i do not know why

Comment: You have to pass all column names in sql query instead `SELECT *` use `SELECT unique_id, name, email `and then list same values in `bind_result` `$stmt->bind_result($row_user_id, $row_user_name, $row_user_email);` check my answer i mentioned it there

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = $stmt->bind_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

[`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) returns `bool`. You're trying to call `bool::fetch_assoc()` with this syntax.